# Review queue flag allowance curiosity

Tags: discussion, flags

When reviewing the Triage questions I see I am allowed to flag 11 questions per day. I have never had to use this limit in a single day, however was curious if everyone has an 11 flag limit, or is it relative to your rep score? Only curious as 11 is an odd number, did the other Steve just choose this number randomly or as previously queried is it based on something such as rep?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [flag privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

> When you start out, you are allotted **10** flags per day. This number may increase to up to **100** flags per day:
>
> - You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
> - You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags minus declined flags).

You've successfully flagged [15 times currently](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1616731/tim-wilkinson?tab=topactivity) so you get 1 extra flag over the default 10

Comment: My lack of research has been my downfall, many thanks!